# How to edit the style of a web form

Tags: html

So in my CSS I already have a class for my text which makes a clear white box appear behind the text to make it more readable, I would also like to do this for my login page, Id like to make it a black box in the middle of the screen sort of like the steam login page https://store.steampowered.com/login/ but putting it in a div and class doesnt seem to work.

ive tried putting the div in the form and ive also tried putting the form in the div

```
</div>
<form>
<div class="acc">
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="Username">
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="Password">
</div>
</form>
```

```
.acc(
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color:black; 
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding:20px 47px;
}
```

Comment: do you want to style `input` tag?

Comment: I want to make the entire form inside a black box just like i did for the rest of the site.  I was able to place text inside a white clear box.

Comment: see hoe on the steam login page the whole form is inside that blue box? thats what i want to do.  https://store.steampowered.com/login/

Answer (score 0):

Try styling the input elements either directly or by applying a class to them. See a working demo below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #252831;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}

.input-wrap {
  margin: 5px;
}

input {
  background-color: #353A47;
  border: 1px solid #4C4B63;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
   <div class="input-wrap">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password">
  </div> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is similar to another answer, I've changed the font colour so it will display, rather than black text on a black background

```
input {
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 30px;
   line-height: normal;
   color: #ffffff;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   background-color:black; 
   text-align:center;
   vertical-align: middle; 
   padding:20px 47px;
}
```